# Erasing C comments with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to erase all comments in $string which contains data from some C file.
The thing I need to replace looks like this:

```
something before that shouldnt be replaced
/*
*  some text in between with / or * on many lines
*/
something after that shouldnt be replaced
```

and the result should look like this:

```
something before that shouldnt be replaced
something after that shouldnt be replaced
```

I have tried many regular expressions but neither work the way I need.
Here are some latest ones:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\/\*(.*?)\*\//u", "", $string);
```

and

```
$string = preg_replace("/\/\*[^\*\/]*\*\//u", "", $string);
```

Note: the text is in UTF-8, the string can contain multibyte characters.

Comment: In php double quoted strings need to have \\ to be interpreted as a '\' by the regex engine

Comment: Do you care about `$string = '/*hello*/'` or other weird cases?

Comment: @bishop If the answer is yes, then OP should not use regexp for this. By the way, your example is not at all weird, it is a normal case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to do this perfectly without ending up writing a full C parser.

Consider the following, for example:

```
// Not using /*-style comment here.
// This line has an odd number of " characters.
while (1) {
    printf("Wheee!
        (*\/*)
         \\// - I'm an ant!
    ");
    /* This is a multiline comment with a // in, and
    // an odd number of " characters. */
}
```

So, from the above, we can see that our problems include:

- multiline quote sequences should be ignored within doublequotes. Unless those doublequotes are part of a comment.
- single-line comment sequences can be contained in double-quoted strings, and in multiline strings.

Here's one possibility to address some of those issues, but far from perfect.

```
// Remove "-strings, //-comments and /*block-comments*/, then restore "-strings.
// Based on regex by mauke of Efnet's #regex.
$file = preg_replace('{("[^"]*")|//[^\n]*|(/\*.*?\*/)}s', '\1', $file);
```

Answer (score 2):

You would also want to add the `s` modifier to tell the regex that `.*` should include newlines. I always think of `s` to mean "treat the input text as a `s`ingle line"

So something like this should work:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\\/\\*(.*?)\\*\\//us", "", $string);
```

Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/XVo9Tp

Edit: Added extra escape slashes to the regex as Brandin suggested because he is right.

Comment: I always use "us" in my php regexp because im american. Haha,, of course u is unicode and `s` is "single line mode" as you say. Which is kind of a funny thing to call it because it allows you to process multiple lines.

Comment: @Brandin It allows you to process multiple lines as if they were just a single line. At least that is how I think about it. There is also a `m` modifier to treat the data as multiline.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think regexp fit good here. What about wrote a very small parse to remove this? I don't do PHP coding for a long time. So, I will try to just give you the idea (simple alogorithm) I haven't tested this, it's just to you get the idea, as I said:

```
buf = new String() // hold the source code without comments
pos = 0
while(string[pos] != EOF) {
  if(string[pos] == '/') {
    pos++;
    while(string[pos] != EOF)
    {
      if(string[pos] == '*' && string[pos + 1] == '/') {
       pos++;
       break;
      }
      pos++;
    }
  }
  buf[buf_index++] = string[pos++];
}
```

where:

`string` is the C source code

`buf`   a dynamic allocated string which expands as needed

Comment: This appears exactly equivalent to the regular expression:

    `$str = preg_replace('{/((?!\*/).)+\*/}s', '/', $str);`

That is, it will delete everything from any '/' to the next '*/' or eof, but will leave the last slash. While regex is a poor choice for this problem, an even simpler state machine is no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`$string = preg_replace("#\/\*\n?(.*)\*\/\n?#ms", "", $string);`

Use **#** as regexp boundaries; change that *u* modifier with the right ones: **m (PCRE_MULTILINE)** and **s (PCRE_DOTALL)**.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

It is important to note that my regexp does not find more than one "comment block"... Use of "dot match all" is generally not a good idea.

Comment: The `m` modifier is not necessary. From the manual: `If there are no "\n" characters in a subject string, or no occurrences of ^ or $ in a pattern, setting this modifier has no effect`. There are no `^` or `$` in the pattern.

Comment: For further code-golfing, the first \n seems unnecessary also, as it is included in the .* because of the use of PCRE_DOTALL.
More seriously, though, the (.*) should probably be (?:.*?) instead.
The "?:" meaning "don't waste memory capturing the insides of this comment" isn't that important, but the ".*?" is vital - otherwise it will maximally match, replacing the string "foo /*bar*/ baz /*quux*/ xyzzy" with "foo  xyzzy" instead of "foo  baz  xyzzy".